# Flutter: get first day of the week and last day of the week?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make some pagination that holds the records that are on the same week.

So the interval will be between monday 00:00 - sunday 23:59

All this in unix time. So I can query the database the records that are between this interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();    

int daysOfWeek = now.weekday - 1;
DateTime firstDay = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day - daysOfWeek);
DateTime lastDay = firstDay.add(Duration(days: 6, hours: 23, minutes: 59));

print(firstDay);
print(lastDay);

DateTime nextFirst = firstDay.add(Duration(days: 7));
DateTime nextLast = lastDay.add(Duration(days: 7));

print(nextFirst);
print(nextLast);

DateTime prevFirst = firstDay.subtract(Duration(days: 7));
DateTime prevLast = lastDay.subtract(Duration(days: 7));

print(prevFirst);
print(prevLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

This week first day is

```
DateTime firstDayOfCurrentWeek() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime firstDayOfCurrentWeek =
        now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday - 1));
    return firstDayOfCurrentWeek.clearTime();
  }


  DateTime clearTime() {
    return DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
```